# Como obter os itens duplicados para Ids especificos?

Tags: c#, lista, linq

Como obtenho a lista de itens que se repetem com o mesmo fpId e eclId?

```
var lst = (from fp in FPIds
        from et in ETIds
        from ec in ECIds
        join eclp in ECLP on ec equals eclp.ecId
        join ecl in ECL on eclpId equals clId                                   
        select new  {
                fpId = fp,
                etId = et,
                ecId = ec,
                eclId  
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Recomendo você não encurtar nomes de variáveis, deixa o código muito confuso para quem for ler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui resolver dessa forma, postei como resposta, pois pode ajudar outras pessoas. Obrigado!

```
if (lst.GroupBy(p => new { p.fpId, p.eclId })
       .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
       .Sum(x => x.Count()) == 0){

                }
```